# Why is : $ \mathrm{dim}_{ \mathbb{C} } V(d,n) = \binom{d+n-1}{n-1} $?

Tags: probability, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, combinations

Let $ V(d,n) $ be the vector space over $ \mathbb{C} $, of forms of degree : $d$ , in $ \mathbb{C} [X_1 , \dots , X_n ] $.

How to show that : $ \mathrm{dim}_{ \mathbb{C} } V(d,n) = \binom{d+n-1}{n-1} $ ?

I think $ \mathrm{dim}_{ \mathbb{C} } V(d,n) = \mathrm{Card} \big( \{ (i_1 , \dots , i_n ) \in \{ 1 , \dots , n \}^n \ | \ i_1 + \dots + i_n = d \} \big) $
but, why is : $ \mathrm{Card} \big( \ \{ (i_1 , \dots , i_n ) \in \{ 1 , \dots , n \}^n \ | \ i_1 + \dots + i_n = d \ \} \big) = \binom{d+n-1}{n-1} $ ?
This is in reality a combinatoric question, so we need to take in account repetition, without order. but, i still not understand why it's equal to : $ \binom{d+n-1}{n-1} $.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think of it this way. You have $d$ balls in a row. You want to put $n-1$ dividers between them to form $n$ sections (some dividers might end up in the same space). How many ways you can put those dividers in? 

It's easy to map solutions to above to different monomials of degree $d$ in $n$ variables.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but why is $ n-1 $ instead of $ n $ ? This is what i don't really understand. :-)

Comment: How many dividers do you need to separate a row of indistinguishable balls into two groups? Two?

Comment: I think we need only one divider.

Comment: This may be useful: [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: This question has definitely been asked before in the site :) See especially froggie's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516850/show-that-dim-h0-mathbbpn-mathcalo-mathbbpnm-n-m-choos)